# Add a progress bar to an existing code (Keep the latest file of each group and delete the rest)

Tags: powershell

I created a PowerShell file using information from internet.
It allows me to keep the latest file of each day and delete the rest

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\mypath'                                                                    
$filePrefix   = 'U_07_'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "$filePrefix*.csv" -File |   
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '_\d{14}$' } |                    
    Group-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.Date }} |  
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group | 
            Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |           
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                     
            Remove-Item -Force                                   
        }
```

I would like to add a progress bar to the script i made. While it seems easy to do a progress bar with a simple code to delete files, when it comes to manage groups i cannot figure out how to incorporate a progress bar in it.

Below my attempt :

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\mypath'                                                                    # put the path to the folder where your files are here
$filePrefix   = 'U_07_'
$Events = Get-EventLog -LogName system


Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "$filePrefix*.csv" -File |   
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '_\d{14}$' } |                    
    Group-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.Date }} |  
        $Events | ForEach-Object -Begin {  
        Clear-Host
        $i= 0
        } -Process{
            $_.Group | 
            Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |           
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                     
            Remove-Item -Force
            $i=$i+1
            Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($i/$Events.count*100)
        } -End
```

And the error i get  :

```
At C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Script\test.ps1:13 char:9
+         $Events | ForEach-Object -Begin {
+         ~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Hoping somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: What is the current behavior you're getting? Just no progress bar at all? Or is something displaying incorrectly? Or are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi i'm getting an error, i added the error in my post. The update of the question did not work..

Comment: I'm updating my answer to account for this, but the increment thing will also cause you problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things going on here. First, you can't pipe `Group-Object` into `$Events`. Remove the pipe suffix `|` from the preceeding line to fix the error.

Second, I missed this in my original answer but you have a trailing `-End` argument of your last [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1). You either need to remove the argument or provide a `ScriptBlock` as this is what the `-End` parameter requires.

---

### Edit 2: For a global progress bar

Based on your comments, and after re-reading your original sample, I'm not clear why you're iterating over the System event log to remove files from the filesystem when you're not using any of the event data or basing your progress bar off that. I'm going to omit this since there's no reason to use it based on what you've provided.

If you want a *global* progress bar per your comment (this wasn't in your question), it complicates things a bit but here's how you do it:

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\mypath'
$filePrefix = 'U_07_'

$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "$filePrefix*.csv" -File |
  Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '_\d{14}$' } |
  Group-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.Date } } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Skip 1 }

$filesToDelete | ForEach-Object -Begin {
  $i = 0
} -Process {
  Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($i++ / $filesToDelete.Count * 100)
  Remove-Item $_ -Force
} -End {
  Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Completed
}
```

Basically, set `$filesToDelete` to the actual files and not the file groups. Notice I iterate over each group in the first `ForEach-Object`, `Sort-Object` descending against LastWriteTime, then skip the first object. This will grab all but the most recent file for each date-group for deletion.

We could just pipe the `Select-Object -Skip 1` to `Remove-Item -Force` within in the first `ForEach-Object` loop like so (multi-line for readability):

```
| ForEach-Object {
  $_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

but since you want the progress bar we needed `$filesToDelete` so we can reference the total file count for the progress bar. Now that we've initialized our fileset, we need to iterate over the files again to remove them, using the `-Begin` block to set the initial counter and the `-End` block to mark the progress bar `-Completed`.

The `-Process` block updates the progress bar, basing the percentage off of the total files to delete instead of the number of events in the event log, then performs the item removal.

To test this, add `-WhatIf` to `Remove-Item` and it will tell the files it would have deleted, without actually deleting them.

> Note: Updating the progress bar does carry some overhead and if you notice an issue with it taking longer than expected to deleted a large number of small files (I mean in the thousands, for example), you can either disable the progress bar with `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` or modify the `-Process` block to only update the progress every few files or so.

---

My original answer indicated that your code wasn't incrementing `$i`, but you've updated your example. Still, if you make use of the unary operator `++` you can simplify what you currently have, though this change is not necessary for your code to function:

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Deleting Files" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ( $i++/$Events.count*100 )
```

Read below for some more information on `++`/`--` and `+=`/`-=`.

---

In case you are unfamiliar, `++` and `--` are unary operators common in several languages which add or subtract `1` from the referenced variable. The actual behavior is nuanced, and can differ between languages but I'll explain the behavior in PowerShell here (`--` subtracts instead of adds):

- `$var++` means "use the value of `$var`, then increment it by 1"
- `++$var` means "increment `$var` by 1, then use the new value"

Curiously, while these are arithmetic operators they behave a bit like assignment operators when used on their own. `$var++` will not output to the console, it updates in place and does not return the result. You can, however, achieve this with [variable squeezing](https://ridicurious.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time/) by wrapping the increment in parentheses: `( $var++ )`

Despite the above behavior, you **do not** need to squeeze `++` or `--` within an expression or equation where its value would be referenced or assigned. This is why we don't need to wrap the `$i++` in its own set of parentheses in `Write-Progress` above.

While I'm on the topic, a related assignment operator is `+=` and `-=`:

- `$var += 2` is shorthand for "add 2 to the value of `$var`"

  - The amount to increment/decrement by can be any number

Unlike `++` and `--`, you *would* need to squeeze this expression to return its value at the time of assignment as you would when assigning any other variable a value.

Comment: yes indeed i forgot to copy the whole code and the incrementing part when i posted my question. No matter if i use $i=$i+1 or $i++ in the -PercentComplete as you suggested, i still get the same error.

Comment: I must have problem of order in my algorithm or something related :(

Comment: I didn't see this comment update, I am still going to leave the info about the unary operators though. They would come in handy here.

Comment: Nice output, thanks a lot. It seems we are getting there, i have now this error :

Comment: [link] https://pastebin.com/2Sdf6XwP

Do not really know what to put in the end loop. 

Also it seems the behavior of the counter is not really what i want since it counts per group and not globally.

Comment: I missed the last line of your script. I'll update my answer when I'm not on mobile in a bit, but either provide a script block for `-End` or remove the reference to it.

Comment: @PotatoeBAM I've updated my answer to either provide a `ScriptBlock` to `-End` or remove the parameter

Comment: @PotatoeBAM I've updated my answer. Please avoid moving the goal posts from your original question again.

Comment: Hi Bender, i did not move my posts from my original question. i stated from the beginning in my first post that i wanted to do a progress bar. I just thought that i could do it using the event log.

That being clarified, thanks a lot for your help. It does what i wanted to achieve. FInally, I wanted to add that i just modified one line in the code in order to be able to execute the script from a different directory that the one of the files being deleted.
`Remove-Item $_.fullname`

Comment: Your original question showed an attempt to implement a progress bar *per group*, not globally. After I provided the answer you said "the behavior of the counter is not what I want since it counts per group and not globally". This is what I meant by "moving the goal posts"; what you wanted was not stated in your original question.

Comment: Not trying to admonish you, just some advice to be clearer of the intent in your question next time